# Inserting newNode in ascending order into LinkedList

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I have some problem when trying to insert newNode into linked list in ascending order. Here is my code:

```
void insertSortedLinkedList(LinkedList *l, int x)
{
ListNode* newN;
ListNode *cur, *previous;

if (l->head == NULL) 
{
    l->head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    l->head->item = x; 
    l->head->next = NULL;
}
else
{
    newN = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    newN->item = x;

    cur = l->head->next; 
    previous = l->head; 

    while (cur!= NULL && cur->item < x) { 
        previous = cur; 
        cur= cur->next; 
    }
    newN->next = cur;
    previous->next = newN;

}
l->size++; 
}
```

With these code, I entered the input as `1,3,5,7,9,6` and I managed to get the output as `1,3,5,6,7,9` which is in ascending order. However, when I tried with `3,2,1` and the output I get was `3,1,2`. The 3 which was the first input does not shift.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'e close. The problem is that your code can never insert a new node as the head in a list that already has an element.

Here's one idea for reorganizing:

```
void insertSortedLinkedList(LinkedList *l, int x)
{
  ListNode* newN;
  ListNode *cur, *previous;

  newN = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
  newN->item = x;

  previous = NULL; 
  cur = l->head; 
  while (cur!= NULL && cur->item < x) { 
    previous = cur; 
    cur= cur->next; 
  }
  if (previous == NULL)
    l->head = newN;
  else
    previous->next = newN;
  newN->next = cur;

  l->size++; 
}
```